# Is there any form of security on paid addons

Tags: add-on, licensing

I just bought an add-on and realised that it's literally a ZIP file with the source visible, just like a regular add-on. I have read the user-term agreement and the EULA, but is there anything preventing me from secretly redistributing the add-on other than moral and legal obligation???

Comment: Nothing is preventing you but your moral

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about addon licensing, not blender

Answer (score 2):

Nope. A lack of DRM goes with the free software culture surrounding Blender.

I obviously can't speak for why any particular addon authors choose to eschew DRM, but it's not uncommon at all. In fact, a number of paid addons are under the GPL and live in public repositories. [Gaffer](https://github.com/gregzaal/Gaffer) and [RetopoFlow](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow), for example.

Gaffer even goes so far as to encourage trying it out before buying; from the [README](https://github.com/gregzaal/Gaffer/blob/master/README.md):

> You can download it here to try it out. If you like it, please consider purchasing it from the Blender Market. $20 isn't much, and every sale puts a smile on my face and motivates me to keep developing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful what you distribute. Some addons can have files bundled within that are licensed with something different than GPL (like assets).

If the file is licensed under GPL, you are free to distribute it or change it under the same license. You can distribute it for free or for money, legally (free software refers to freedom, not cost).

If you re-sell a GPL addon for money and you are not the developer, that is morally very bad. When I am paying for the item, I want the money to support the developer. You would have to scam me and make me think you are the developer for someone like me to buy it. That may be legally wrong, I am not a lawyer though.

Re-distributing for free is morally ok by my standards. The author made it under GPL with willing intention to be free. His profit is based on free software of someone else, he grabbed it freely for free. If the author or community was not morally ok with free distribution, that would be a bit hypocritical imho. Buying is just another form of donating. Some would even consider not morally ok when there is no public source code posted and the author keeps the buy option as the only option to get it first hand. *(If you have a good argument against this, pls share in comment)*.

Comment: I have no conflict against your viable points brother. But that might be one of the few points that keep blender from being industry standard, proprietary tools must be accepted among us, that's how you separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: @ReubenX Oh i meant anyone reading with the last sentence in italic, targeting the morals of distributing paid addons for free, I'd like to hear counter-arguments on that one. You are right about the licencing in industry. But I don't think Blender aims to be industry standard, it fills a space in market and sits in it comfortably. With Cycles the licensing for it changed, so it could integrate with industry better.